# Required and error classes not applied to VF page elements

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system, stylesheets

slds-required and slds-has-error classes are not getting applied to my VF page elements that are styled by SLDS. I have included the style sheet as well:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS090, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
```

The other SLDS classes like slds-grid etc are applied , but these are not working. What could be reason for this?

> Markup

```
<apex:form id="theForm">

    <!-- divContainer -->
    <div id="divContainer" class="slds">       
        <div class="slds-m-around--medium">
           <div class="slds-form-element__group">
                <!-- Document Type -->
                <div class="slds-grid slds-m-bottom--large">                                                                
                    <div id="errorDivPicklist" class="slds-form-element slds-has-error slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-right--x-small">
                        <span class="slds-required" title="required">*</span><label class="slds-form-element__label" for="ddlDocumentType">{!$Label.DOCUMENT_TYPE_LBL}</label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <div class="slds-select_container">
                                    <apex:selectList id="ddlDocumentType" styleClass="slds-select" value="{!documentType}" size="1" required="true">
                                        <apex:SelectOption itemValue="" itemLabel="{!$Label.Select}"/>
                                        <apex:SelectOptions value="{!documentTypes}"/>
                                    </apex:selectList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__help slds-hide" id="error-message-picklist-id">This field is required</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-has-error slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-left--x-small">
                        <span class="slds-required" title="required">*</span><label class="slds-form-element__label" for="txtFileName">{!$Label.NAME_LBL}</label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <apex:inputText styleClass="slds-input" id="txtFileName" value="{!fileName}"" required="true"/> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- divContainer -->
</apex:form>
```

Comment: You might have better luck if you update to the latest version. That's one advantage of using the `<apex:slds />` tag.

Comment: @AdrianLarson : I used the tag. Still not working.

Comment: Did you also remove the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes, I commented it.

Comment: Got the thing here, I was adding <apex:slds /> tag inside <head> tags. After removing head tags, it was applied.